# Linux multithreading with own memory space possible?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, stack, overflow

I have a Linux C program that runs well in a Raspberry 3. When I run it in a low memory situation in another sbc (Raspberry Zero) it runs about 2-3 days then freezes. I believe it's a stack overflow situation.

I've put a thread to check periodically when the main program has frozen. Unfortunately it appears that if the main process crashes, it takes down all of the other threads in the process.

I can avoid this by having another process checking upon the first process, but I'd prefer a thread. Is it possible to have thread that is safe and does not freeze it the main process freezes?

Comment: That's the main difference between threads and processes, whether they share the same address space or not.

Answer (score 1):

Easily no, it's not possible because per thread definition they share memory and they are part of the main process and it own them all. So everything afflict the main process afflict all the threads.